# maven-metadata.xml not appending multiple SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, nexus, build-dependencies

Last time that I was using Maven and Nexus I remember I had maven-metadata like the one below:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <versioning>
        <snapshot>
            <timestamp>20170908.123705</timestamp>
            <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20170908123705</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
    <snapshotVersions>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170906.143113**-1**</value>
            <updated>20170906140847</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170906.143113**-1**</value>
            <updated>20170906140844</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170908.123705**-2**</value>
            <updated>20170908123705</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>1.0-20170908.123705**-2**</value>
            <updated>20170908123705</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
</metadata>
```

**It was keeping a number of SNAPSHOTS**, eg last three (I can't remember where this was setup, if with maven deploy configuration or on Nexus).

All those three SNAPSHOTS were available in the repo and I could specified the timestamp/buildNumber to retrieve a specific one.

I come back to Maven and Nexus after long time, and now when i run a build on the remote nexus server I got instead:

```
   <metadata>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-maven-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <versioning>
            <snapshot>
                <timestamp>20170908.123705</timestamp>
                <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
            </snapshot>
            <lastUpdated>20170908123705</lastUpdated>
        </versioning>
        <snapshotVersions>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
                <extension>jar</extension>
                <value>1.0-20170908.123705-2</value>
                <updated>20170908123705</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <extension>jar</extension>
                <value>1.0-20170908.123705-2</value>
                <updated>20170908123705</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
        </snapshotVersions>
    </metadata>
```

I lost any reference to the previous SNAPSHOT deployed on Nexus. They are available in the Nexus, **but the metadata does not list them, essentially it list just the latest uploaded**.

Where should I configure in order to keep track of the latest "number" of SNAPSHOT uploaded instead of just the last one? 
Is this a maven deploy plugin configuration missing somewhere or is just something changed Maven side?

I'm using maven 3.6.3

Comment: Why are you interested in the content of `maven-metadata.xml`? It is just an internal file for Maven to handle downloads of SNAPSHOTs. How many SNAPSHOTs are kept in the Nexus depends on the policies defined in Nexus itself. You could e.g. configure Nexus to delete all but the last version.

Comment: HI @JFMeier, I need to use it to retrieve information about the SNAPSHOT timestamp, and to run comparison between every timestamped SNAPSHOT uploaded, it is odd, but it is also a requirement, I did not find any setup on Nexus to define this policy, i'll take a look again...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the Nexus REST API to retrieve the information?

Comment: Yeah I can do it, thanks for the suggestion, but still would like to understand why the maven metadata does not list them, as far I can check online, it should